# How to add some text along with the screen captures

Tags: html, css

I am using following line of code to create hyperlink in html.

```
 <a href="../imagefile.jpg" target="_blank">Screen Capture</a>
```

When I click on the hyperlink the saved image is getting opened in browser successfully. Now I want to know if there is a way to display some text along with the screen capture. The html contains more than 100 such hyperlinks points to different screen captures. I want to add some text along with each image when it displays in the browser.

Comment: The images is loaded in the browser, you can't add text there. But you could make a page where you load the file in the HTML and add a text to it. Or use a gallery like fancybox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that's not possible. Not if you just link to the image. You could, however:

- Add the text to the image itself.
- Create an HTML page for the image which contains the text.
- Use Javascript to display the image with some text on your page.
- Use some server-side language to dynamically generate a HTML page containing the image and the text you requested.